# Altering transparency / thickness of rising smoke

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, smoke-simulation

How can I create a more transparent, thinner bottom area of smoke, then rising higher to be much thicker and opaque? It will not need to be animated.

Comment: Perhaps turn on flame and use its material properties to drive opacity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a Gradient texture to control the mix between the smoke density and a transparent shader.

You can use generated coordinates and a mapping node to control the placement. In this case note the rotation on the $Y$ axis.

After the Gradient texture you can use color ramp to control the placement for the transparency.

[image]

Comment: Very fancy: mathjax for axis names.